# Function php argument

Tags: php, function, arguments

something is wrong in one of my functions. The others work fine.
The application has a MVC structure. Beginning with objects and MVC, I must ay. 
Basically, I have a page (services.php) linking to:

```
echo"<a href=\"index.php?page=detailservices&id=".$data['id']." \">Plus      d'informations...</a>";
```

Function in the model page (model.php):

```
function get_NextServ($id)
{
global $bdd;
$id = (int)$id;
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM entreprises WHERE id= ?');
$req->execute(array($id));
return $req;
}
```

And the detailservices.php page:

```
try
{
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $billet = get_NextServ($id);


    if (get_NextServ($id) < 1)
    {
        echo "No......";
    } else
    {
        foreach ($billet as $data)
        {
            echo "<h2>" . $data['entreprise'] . "</h2>";
        }
        .....
```

I have the following errors:
Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_NextServ(), called in projects\myapp-v3\controllers\controllers.php on line 27 and defined in projects\myapp-v3\model\model.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined variable: id in projects\myapp-v3\model\model.php on line 57

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in projects\myapp-v3\model\model.php on line 59

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your URL points to index with a parameter of detailservices. Can we see index, please? I'm guessing you're not passing var through from there? Have you tried a quick die(var_dump($_GET ['id'])); in details page at the start? Actually I see you're checking isset does the else not fire?

Comment: if($_GET['page']=='detailservices'){
   getDetailServices()
   }

Comment: That's in the index? Does that function fire off to a url which includes id? If  not I think that's the issue.

Comment: The index page is actually my front controller. 
if($_GET['page']=='detailservices'){
   getDetailServices()
   }
The function which is called is this one (controller.php):

        function getDetailServices()
 {
  $titre = 'title';
  $keywords= 'services...';
  $billets= get_NextServ();
  $inclusion = 'detailservices.php';
  require 'view/templates/gabarit-general.php';

 }

I'm also trying a var_dump right now in the page detailservices.php

Comment: I hope I'm not missing something silly which compensates for this but you don't pass the I'd parameter here? $billets= get_NextServ();

Comment: ok, this works fine now. I had to change it to get_NextServ($id);